# What kind of alignments can I get for a Honda Civic?

Tags: honda, civic, alignment

I'm watching [this video, *"Front Strut Replacement 9th Gen Honda Civic 2013"* and they say,](https://youtu.be/1t3ngKl1sQ4?t=840)

> *"On this particular Honda Civic there is no camber adjustment or caster adjustment the only adjustment is toe-in toe-out camber is set to 0 degrees from factory there are no camber installed in those pinch bolts therefore camber in theory should not have moved"*

Does this mean there is no way for a professional to adjust camber or caster the Honda Civic? I learned from this answer [there are three types of alignment](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/59039/999). If there is really is no method to do camber and caster adjustment, should I just ask for a quote to do toe-in and toe-out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no adjustment for camber and caster, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't be checked. If the vehicle's camber/caster is out of alignment, that means there are bigger problems, such as worn out or damaged parts. Getting it checked will give you an idea of where your vehicle stands overall. If either one of these is out, there's a good chance you'll need tire replacement soon due to excess wear on them. IOW: It's not a bad idea.

Comment: Is it normal for a mechanic to check the camber/caster if you get a  toe-in toe-out alignment? And also, if it is out you don't actually say what kind of worn our or damaged parts may be broken: is it a thing to have a broken part that results in camber/caster being out of alignment and for the car to otherwise function such that I need a professional to diagnose this? Basically, I'm just wondering if it's sufficient to only price around for the alignment I know I need.

Comment: I mean, it's your car. If you feel there are no broken/worn parts (which there may not be), then just ask for a toe adjustment. Parts which could be broken/worn are many, but include things like lower ball joints, upper strut mount, or bent/damaged lower A-arm (to name a few).